# Which "change of variable" can convert a function to an EVEN function?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

For a function, such as:

$$ f(x)=xe^{-x}$$

Is there a transform which can convert it to an EVEN function ?
We know the following method will generate an even function:

$$ g(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$$

But that is not what we are looking. Can we generate an EVEN function from $f(x)$ using some kind of "change of variable“ ？For example, $x = h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is a function ?

Comment: This is very vague.  For any function, $f(|x|)$ is even, as is $f(x^2)$...is that good enough?  Explicit examples of the sort of thing you are looking for might help.

Comment: If it is a change of variable, it should be $x=h(y),$ not $x=h(x),$ which would be something else.

Comment: You certainly can't do this for all functions, like $f(x)=x^3,$ at least if $h$ is meant to be a bijection (so a true change of variables.) This is because a $x^3$ is a bijection, while an even function never is. More generally, there must be exactly one $y$ such that $n_y=|f^{-1}(y)|$ is odd, assuming the domain is $\mathbb R.$ This is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: You have $\lim_{x\to-\infty} xe^{-x}=-\infty,$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} xe^{-x}=0.$ So there is not bijective continuous $h$ which will work.

Comment: However, you might be able to find a local solution  for $xe^{-x}$ with $h(0)=1$ and $h:\mathbb R\to(0,+\infty).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how to do this ?

Comment: Be specific, I've written a lot of comments here. @david

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, $xe^{-xx}$ with $h(0)= 1$ and $R\to(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: It can be done with something like $h(y)=e^y$ for $x\leq 0,$ and some messy thing involving the Lambert $W_1$-function for $y>0.$ But you can do this for any $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ which converges to the same value has $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to \infty,$ and where $x$ is increasing on $(0,a)$ and decreasing on $(a,\infty).$ We just don't always have a useful function like Lambert's to make it fully definable.

Comment: Thank you for point out Lambert $W_1$.